C++: Lambda with conditional capture clause possible?
Is there a way to define a lambda's capture clause (copy vs. reference) conditionally?
Let's say we have a function taking a functor:
template<typename Func>
void takeFunctor( Func&& func ){ func(); }

and another that passes a lambda to it:
template<int tparam>
void consumer(){
    std::vector<int> expensiveToCopy (1000000)
    takeFunctor( <capture-clause>(){
        /* do something with expensiveToCopy */
    } );
}

Is there any way to conditionally define the capture clause, e.g. based on the template parameter tparam? Maybe some typedef for the lambda with std::conditional? Thus far, I think the answer is 'no', but I'd love to be wrong.
One use case would be execution on host vs. device, where one could then set both an object's type and the (kernel) lambda's capture clause based on the target.
EDIT: To clarify, I want to achieve basically the same as this, but avoid the duplication of the lambda's body:
template<int tparam>
void consumer(){
    std::vector<int> expensiveToCopy (1000000)
    if constexpr (tparam == 0){
        takeFunctor( [&](){ <body>; } );
    } else {
        takeFunctor( [=](){ <body>; } );
    }
}


Would if constexpr (/*some check on tparam */) takeFunctor(/* lambda1 */); else takeFunctor(/* lambda2 */); work?

You mean something like [(condition)?&a:&b]?

not sure  if I  understand the question. Wouldn't  host vs. device be different code anyhow?

@cigien I mean, technically yes, but I don't see a non-macro way to avoid duplication of the lambda's body. It's of course the first idea that comes to mind, but it's hard to maintain and thus not practically feasible.

@πάντα ῥεῖ Ah, I see that my question could be misunderstood that way, and edited the first sentence. What I mean is [(condition)?&a:=a].

Why don't you just always capture by reference? What is the use case here?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai For all backends that I am familiar with (CUDA, HIP, SYCL, OpenMP, OpenACC), you can use some abstraction to pass a copy-capturing lambda to a generic (i.e. templated) kernel. For CUDA/HIP, you'd have to add __host__ __device__ to the lambda signature. I'm pretty sure that the portability library Kokkos also does it that way.

@Jan Schultke see last sentence of the question, which specifically starts with "One use case". You can only use copy-capturing lambdas as device code, and it's best to capture only trivially copyable objects that way.

That still seems like a very artificial use case. When do you need to conditionally use a lambda as host code or device code depending on a template parameter? Why would you not be able to always copy in that example? Why can you not just make a function object by hand instead of using lambdas? What is the use case? Your example still doesn't make much sense because expensiveToCopy is entirely local to the function and can probable be made static const, and then you don't need to capture it anyway.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. I'm telling you that based on my experience with multiple device backends, it may be helpful to be able to conditionally define a capture clause. If your sensibilities tell you that that's too artificial a case, then feel free to skip this question.
In my case, I'd like to reuse preallocated buffers on the host, while creating stack buffers on the device. I could do that with additional indirection and copy-capture raw pointers, but I'd like to try out options.

It should not be up to the compiler to select pass by value or pass by copy. This should be a design choice up front. Imagine passing a reference to a large vector and you use the lambda to start a std::thread... now your vector could go out of scope while the thread is using it (very bad form that). If you have data that is expensive to copy, like your large vector you can also use a std::shared_ptr<std::vector<>> and pass that by value.

@Pepijn Kramer: It would still be up to the user to define the capture clause, even if it's conditional. I don't understand how that would be up to the compiler. I'm also not asking for a runtime condition, but a compile-time condition. So, if it's safe to do with
if constexpr (...){ takeFunctor( [&](){...} ); } else { takeFunctor( [=](){...}; }, then it should be equally safe with a conditional capture clause, or am I missing your point?

Not sure if this answers your question. Though you can capture a value optionally. And that value can be a pointer to the to be or not to be copied data:
#include <iostream>

void test(bool b) {
    int x = 42;
    [a = (b ? &x : nullptr)]() -> void {
        if (a != nullptr) {
            int c = *a;
            std::cout << c;
        }
    }();
}

int main() {
    test(true);
    test(false);
}


Concerning your EDIT, if you want to avoid code duplciation, use a function. Or lambda:
template<int tparam>
void consumer(){
    std::vector<int> expensiveToCopy (1000000)

    auto f = [](/*...*/){  <body>; };

    if constexpr (tparam == 0){
        takeFunctor( [&,f](){ f(/*...*/); } );
    } else {
        takeFunctor( [=](){ f(/*...*/); } );
    }
}


An interesting idea. Is there any way to expand that to all captured variables automatically?
About the EDIT: In <body>, I'd still want to do something with expensiveToCopy, so a capture would still be needed and can't be solved via indirection to a non-capturing lambda or free function.

@RL-S yes it can be done with a non-capturing lambda, because f would get anything it needs get passed from the outer lambda as normal parameter

@RL-S the point is that you cannot use captures on f when f is defined first (outside of the if) but is inteded to use expensiveCopy as it has been cpatured by the outer lambda (either by ref or by value)  (trying to use captures on f would just take you back to square one)

ah, now I see that you want to pass it as parameters. My question is still about a conditional definition of the capture clause - the EDIT only meant to illustrate what the condition was supposed to achieve. I don't want to have to implement a constexpr if condition at every point where takeFunctor is called. There's also the additional problem that now the arguments to f have to be a conditional type, so it's not particularly suitable as an approach on the consumer side of a library.

@RL-S the part concerning your EDIT in the answer is only an additiion. The first part of the answer shows how you can conditionally pass a pointer and the make a copy or not make a copy.

@RL-S similar to others, I am still confused by the use case. I mean either takeFunctor should modify expensiveToCopy or not. It cannot be both.

Here's my use case, as short as I can write it: Unified code for execution either on CPUs (host) or GPUs (device) is desirable. Types, functions, etc. can easily be specialised dependent on the execution environment (host/device) for efficient computations. Except the lambda clause: For host execution, reference capture can be both more intuitive and efficient, but for device execution, copy-capture is the only way. And thus far, I couldn't find a good abstraction for this, especially not one that feels elegant and easy to use.
